# Twitter Streaming API connection times out after 3 hours

Tags: r, twitter, twitter-streaming-api

I'm trying to use the Twitter Streaming API to collect data from Twitter.

below is my code in r

```
filterStream(oauth=my_oauth, 
         timeout = 0, track = keyword,
         file.name = "tweets.json") 
       tweetsdf = parseTweets("tweets.json", simplify = TRUE) 
       View(tweetsdf)
```

You can see that i have set the timeout to 0 which should mean that the connection is always on. but what i'm finding is that my connection is dropped after just under 3 hours.

Comment: guessing english Isnt your first language? can you explain a bit more and someone may be able to help reword your question with you to make it clearer.

Comment: is it clear ???

Comment: i dont know much about the twitter streaming API but i've made some edits so when its been reviewed it should will make the question clearer and attract some answers for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want the connection to timeout because Twitter will drop the connection when there is no activity after 90 seconds. Put your code inside a `try` block inside a `while` loop. That way you can reconnect when your connection drops.

Comment: `library(streamR) 
end.date <- as.Date("2017-09-01")

while (Sys.Date() < end.date){

filterStream(oauth=my_oauth, # Save tweets in a json file
             timeout = 0, track = keyword, #(timeout) in a second
             file.name = "tweets.json") 
}

tweetsdf = parseTweets("tweets.json", simplify = TRUE)
# parse the json file and save to a data frame called tweets.df
View(tweetsdf)`
but the resulting: 'tweetsdf' not found 
Can you help me edit the code?